# Inventory Collection in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

This is what the teacher is asking:
User selects an item from the list

The information about the item displays to the right (description, retail price, units)

The user enters a quantity and clicks Add to Cart

The subtotal, tax and grand total display

User clicks complete purchase button and a confirm order box appears. User clicks OK and the form clears for another transaction.

This is what I done:
Any Suggestions as of why I keep getting this error `"Argument Index is not a valid value"`

```
Imports System.IO


Public Class MainForm

Const strFILENAME As String = "Inventory.txt"
Dim dblTaxRate As Double = 8.75

Dim InventoryCollection As New Collection

Public Sub AddRecord(ByVal InvItem As Inventory)
    Try


        inventoryCollection.Add(InvItem, InvItem.InventoryNumber)


    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub



Private Sub ClearMainForm()
    txtDesc.Text = String.Empty
    txtRetail.Text = ""
    txtOnHand.Text = ""
    txtInvNumber.Text = String.Empty
End Sub




Private Sub UpdateListBox()
    lstInventory.Items.Clear()

    Dim InvItem As Inventory

    For Each InvItem In inventoryCollection
        lstInventory.Items.Add(InvItem.InventoryNumber)
    Next
    If lstInventory.Items.Count > 0 Then
        lstInventory.SelectedIndex = 0
    Else
        ClearMainForm()
    End If

End Sub


Private Sub SaveRecord(ByVal objInventory As Inventory)

    Dim Writer As StreamWriter
    Try

        Writer = File.AppendText("Inventory.txt")
        Writer.WriteLine(objInventory.InventoryNumber)
        Writer.WriteLine(objInventory.Description)
        Writer.WriteLine(objInventory.Retail.ToString())
        Writer.WriteLine(objInventory.OnHand.ToString())


    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub MainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim objInventory As New Inventory
    Dim inventoryFile As System.IO.StreamReader
    Dim blnFound As Boolean = False
    Dim inventoryCollection As New Collection


    Try
        ' Open the file.
        If System.IO.File.Exists(strFILENAME) Then

        End If


        inventoryFile = System.IO.File.OpenText(strFILENAME)


        'Enter loop and read till end of file.
        Do Until inventoryFile.Peek = -1


            'Read lines from file, save into Inventory object properties.
            objInventory.InventoryNumber = inventoryFile.ReadLine
            objInventory.Description = inventoryFile.ReadLine
            objInventory.PartCost = inventoryFile.ReadLine
            objInventory.Retail = inventoryFile.ReadLine
            objInventory.OnHand = inventoryFile.ReadLine

            'Display data in text boxes.
            lstInventory.Items.Add(objInventory.InventoryNumber)




        Loop
        'Close the file.
        inventoryFile.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    End Try


End Sub

Private Sub DisplayInput(ByVal InvItem As Inventory)
    'Display from Collection to Label boxes

    Try

        txtDesc.Text = InvItem.Description
        txtOnHand.Text = InvItem.OnHand.ToString()
        txtRetail.Text = InvItem.Retail.ToString()
        txtInvNumber.Text = InvItem.InventoryNumber

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    End Try
End Sub


Private Sub lstInventory_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstInventory.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim objInventory As Inventory

    'See if an Item is Selected
    If lstInventory.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then

        'Retrieve student's data from inventoryCollection. Convert object into Inventory object.
        Try

            objInventory = CType(inventoryCollection.Item(lstInventory.SelectedItem), Inventory)

        Catch ex As Exception
            'Display error message.
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            Console.WriteLine("")
        End Try
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    'Clear Form
    ClearMainForm()
End Sub

Private Sub btnExits_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExits.Click
    'Close the Form
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click


    Dim InvID As New Inventory



    InventoryCollection.Add(InvID, InvID.InventoryNumber)

End Sub
End Class

Public Class Inventory


Private StrinvNumber As String
Private strdesc As String
Private decCost As Decimal
Private decretailPrice As Decimal
Private IntqtyOnHand As Integer



'Constructor
Public Sub New()
    StrinvNumber = String.Empty
    strdesc = String.Empty
    decCost = 0.0
    decretailPrice = 0.0
    IntqtyOnHand = 0.0

End Sub



Public Property InventoryNumber() As String
    Get
        Return StrinvNumber
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        StrinvNumber = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Description() As String
    Get
        Return strdesc
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        strdesc = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property PartCost() As Decimal
    Get
        Return decCost
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
        decCost = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Retail() As Decimal
    Get
        Return decretailPrice
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
        decretailPrice = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property OnHand() As Integer
    Get
        Return IntqtyOnHand
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        IntqtyOnHand = value

    End Set
End Property




End Class
```

Comment: There's a lot of code there.  You might try pointing out where that exception is thrown so we don;t have to waste our time trying to work out something that you already know.  Please provide **all** the relevant information.

Comment: I think the listbox cannot read the Inventory Collection.

Comment: Private Sub lstInventory_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstInventory.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim objInventory As Inventory

    'See if an Item is Selected
    If lstInventory.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then

        Try

            objInventory = CType(inventoryCollection.Item(lstInventory.SelectedItem), Inventory)

        Catch ex As Exception
            'Display error message.
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            Console.WriteLine("")
        End Try
    End If
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the issue is here:

```
objInventory = CType(inventoryCollection.Item(lstInventory.SelectedItem), Inventory)
```

Does `lstInventory` contain `Integer` values and are those values valid indexes into `inventoryCollection`?  I would expect not.  Are those two lists supposed to correspond to each other?  If so then you should be using `SelectedIndex` rather than `SelectedItem`.  Probably you should have just bound the list to the `ListBox` in the first place and then the `SelectedItem` would be the object you needed already.

Comment: yes I guess I didnt declare any collections. Just this:Dim InventoryCollection As New Collection. What do I need to add .

Comment: Your comment sounds like you didn't read my answer. If you want to use the SelectedItem as an index then each item must be a valid index. Are they? What are the items in the ListBox?

Comment: Got It. I will Index the items and retry the code. Hope that works

Comment: How do Index Items, Like this: Private Sub Index(ByVal Inventory)

        InventoryItem(1).InventoryNumberString = "A804"
        InventoryItem(1).DescriptionString = "College Logo Tshirt"
        IInventoryItem(1).PartCost = 15
        InventoryItem(1).OnHand = 18.99D


    End Sub

Comment: I didn't tell you to index the items.  Please read the words.  The items themselves must be indexes.  I asked you a question in my previous comment and I did so for a reason.  What are the items in the ListBox?

Comment: User selects an item from the list (InventoryNumber) A String, The information about the item displays to the right (description, retail price, units) Retail and Units As Decimal. My issue is when I select the Item from the list Box it gives me this error ("Argument Index is not a valid value")

Comment: Then it's not an index, so don't use it as an index.